# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object in CNN-LSTM model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

I was trying to build a CNN-LSTM hybrid model for image classification with two class but at the time of fitting the model I have faced an error as `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`.
The code is mentioned in below,

```
import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                                    rescale=1./255,
                                    shear_range=0.2,
                                    zoom_range=0.2,
                                    horizontal_flip=True)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                    'Dataset/Train',
                                    target_size=(64, 64),
                                    batch_size=32,
                                    class_mode='binary')
validation = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                    'Dataset/Validation',
                                    target_size=(64, 64),
                                    batch_size=32,
                                    class_mode='binary'
)
test= test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                    'Dataset/Test',
                                    target_size=(64, 64),
                                    batch_size=32,
                                    class_mode='binary')


#initializing the CNN
model = Sequential()

#convolution2D
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(32,3,3, input_shape = (64,64,3), activation = 'relu')))
#adding maxpooling 
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(2, 2)))
#Flattening
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

model.add(LSTM(units= 20, input_shape = (1,5), return_sequences = True ))
model.add(LSTM(units = 20))

#Full Connection
model.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(units = 2, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(
        generator=train,
        steps_per_epoch=2,
        validation_data=validation,
        epochs=5
    )
```

The error is given in attached file, please check it and help me.

[image: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object]

Comment: Why are you adding the model as a layer to itself?

Comment: Please do **not** post screenshots (of code, data, error messages...); see how to create a [mre]

Comment: The comment of @xdurch0 hits the spot, your line `model.add(TimeDistributed(model))` is wrong. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @xdurch0, sorry, it's my mistakes. i remove the line.

Answer (score 1):

you cat increase this limit with [sys.setrecursionlimit(biggerlimit)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit) but this is discouraged.
rather, try to reshape your model so as to not hit this limit